# Autocomplete plugin for RTE in CQ

Tags: aem

I want to customize the RTE in CQ. I will input some complex medical terminologies to the CRX through scaffolding. Whenever author writes an article they should be able to autocomplete these terminologies. I see that there is a Jquery plugging for autocomplete but how do I include this in my CQ RTE.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on the previous versions of CQ but CQ 5.6 + uses Extjs 3.4.0 which provides ext js htmleditor may be you can try using that. There is very less documentation on creating custom plugins for autocomplete in RichTextEditor. Also not sure but I think you might not be able to use the jquery plugins for RTE since they are integrated for ext js plugins only. Here is the reference for html editor for extjs 3.4.0 http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.HtmlEditor . Hope this helps.